# "Error: array used as initializer" in constructor

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

For some reason, the constructor of my PassServer object always gives an "array used as initializer" error using GCC, just pointing at the first line of the constructor. The full error is:

```
passserver.cpp: In constructor âPassServer::PassServer(std::size_t)â:
passserver.cpp:10:58: error: array used as initializer
PassServer::PassServer(std::size_t size) : passwords(size)
                                                         ^
In file included from hashtable.h:56:0,
             from passserver.h:15,
             from passserver.cpp:2:
hashtable.hpp: In instantiation of âcop4530::HashTable<K, V>::HashTable(size_t) [with K = std::basic_string<char>; V = std::basic_string<char>; size_t = long unsigned int]â:
passserver.cpp:10:58:   required from here
hashtable.hpp:13:16: error: array used as initializer
: currentSize{0}
               ^
```

Even if you take out `: passwords(size)`, it still results in the same compiling error.
Here are relevant code chunks:

passserver.h:

```
#include "hashtable.h"
...
class PassServer {
public:
PassServer(size_t size = 101);
...
private:
HashTable<string, string> passwords;
...
```

hashtable.h:

```
...
public:
HashTable(size_t size = 101);
std::vector< std::list< std::pair<K, V> >* >* bucketVector;
...
private:
size_t currentSize;
...
```

hashtable.hpp:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
HashTable<K, V>::HashTable(size_t n) : currentSize{0} {
...
bucketVector = new std::vector< std::list<key_value>* >(prime_below(n), NULL);
...
```

If more needs to be provided, I will update. It's an assignment, so I'm trying not to show what isn't relevant to my error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What other members do you have in `HashTable`? Any array members with C++11-style in-class initializers?

Comment: Sorry, but those are the only variable members: bucketVector and currentSize.

Comment: What if you change the initializer in the `HashTable` constructor to `currentSize(0)` (using parens instead of curly braces)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives the same exact error sequence -- just with (0) instead of {0} being written, obviously. The professor had provided that constructor line for the assignment, so...

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)